# How add startup class to worker service template in .net core 3

Tags: service-worker, .net-core-3.0

I want to add Startup class to worker service template in dotnet core 3 in order to use Configuration as dependency injection. I don't want to use my Program class to configure services. If there is another way to use Configuration, please give me an info about. Thank you.

this is my Standart program class code and I just added Hangfire

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                services.AddHangfire(x =>
                    x.UsePostgreSqlStorage(Configuration.GetConnectionString("defaultConnection"))
                );

                services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
            });
```

I just want to seperate my services to configure in Startup class

```
UseStartup<Startup>();
```

Comment: Is this for a web host?

Comment: No the template gives me defaultbuilder. Not a hostbuilder. I dont know if hangfire will work in default builder or not. Actually It will be much easier to use CreateWebHostBuilder

Comment: @VugarAhmadov Hi. Did you figure out? I would also like to use Startup? Any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
var configuration = hostContext.Configuration;
services.AddHangfire(x => x.UsePostgreSqlStorage(configuration.GetConnectionString("defaultConnection"))
```

else

```
services.AddHangfire(x => x.UsePostgreSqlStorage(hostContext.Configuration.GetConnectionString("defaultConnection"))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no extension method available for this and it requires some manual work to get this to work unfortunately. You simply new up your Startup class, pass in constructor parameters, and call the methods yourself.

For example:

```cs
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
  .ConfigureServices((builder, services) =>
  {
    var startup = new Startup(builder.Configuration);
    startup.ConfigureServices(services);
  })
```